# Out of VRAM while it's not

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I just ran into a problem where Blender would crash during a cycles render with Windows saying it had to be closed since I don't have enough VRAM. I have a 1080ti which has 11gb VRAM. My scene peaks at 7gb~ and just closes mid render. I've monitored it with GPU-Z and MSI Afterburner at the same time, both say 6.9gb VRAM used.[image: Render]

My idle VRAM usage (everything closed for the render) is around 500mb~
[image: Idle]

I couldn't use the blenchmark since a error message pops up and it says that I use different GPU's while I just have one installed, otherwise I would've included that.

My GPU drivers are up to date aswell as Blender itself.

Sure I could just try to minimize the RAM usage overall, but it's clearly not using the full capabilities of my GPU, and CPU rendering takes 7x as long so that's not acceptable either.

Comment: just guessing but maybe that "different GPU" is detected as having less VRAM or something?

Comment: Might be that Windows has a timeout recovery (TDR) system that detects if a GPU can't be accessed by system in a given amount of time - the default  is two seconds. It then “reinitializes” the WDDM driver and resets the GPU. If you are computing difficult stuff, Cycles might cause the gpu not reporting to system for longer than that. This will stop the rendering process. The solution is to set registry key *TdrDelay* at address HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/GraphicsDrivers to value 0 (disabling the timeout). If that solves it I'll write it as answer.

Comment: Did you mean I have to create a Key at the said location? I'm a bit confused.